# Dynamic form Single param how to remove the mat form field

Tags: javascript, angular

I am unable to delete the single param mat form field but I can delete the multiple param form field

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'input'">
  <ng-container *ngIf="param.allowMultiple; else singleParam">
    <mat-form-field [formArrayName]="param.name" *ngFor="let control of controls(param); let i=index"
      appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>{{ param.label}}</mat-label>
      <input  matInput [formControlName]="i" [readonly]="param.readOnly" [required]="param.required">
      <mat-error *ngIf="control.invalid">{{ param.validationErrorMessage || 'Error' }}</mat-error>
      <mat-icon *ngIf="i === 0" class="add-icon" (click)="addControl(param)"
        matTooltip="{{ 'FORM.ADD_FIELD' | translate : { label: param.label } }}">add</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon *ngIf="i > 0" class="remove-icon" (click)="removeControl(param.name, i)"
        matTooltip="{{ 'FORM.REMOVE_FIELD' | translate : { label: param.label } }}">delete</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #singleParam>
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>{{ param.label}}</mat-label>
      <input  matInput [formControlName]="param.name" [readonly]="param.readOnly" [required]="param.required">
      <mat-icon *ngIf="i > 0" class="remove-icon" (click)="removeControl(param.name, i)"
        matTooltip="{{ 'FORM.REMOVE_FIELD' | translate : { label: param.label } }}">delete</mat-icon>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls[param.name].invalid">{{ param.validationErrorMessage || 'Error' }}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

```
  removeControl(name: string, index: number): void {
    const control = this.form.get(name) as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(index);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `removeControl()` method works in the first case, because the control belongs to a [`FormArray`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray), so you can call [`FormArray#removeAt`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#removeat).

However, in the case of the single element doesn't live in a `FormArray`, but rather a [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup).  To remove an element from a FormGroup, use [`FormGroup#removeControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#removecontrol).